# Is there an easy way to determine what columns/ cells are referenced in Excel formulae?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm working with a large data set in Excel with ~50 columns of data and tens of thousands of rows.

- There are other sheets that refer to that data and use that data in different pivots, calculations, etc.
- Some of the columns, though, are not used, so I'd like to delete them.
- Is there an easy way to figure out which columns are or are not used in any formulae?

Comment: You mean, short of reading the forumula to see what's referenced in it?

Comment: Yeah, there are lots of formulae throughout the other sheets that reference data on the main sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the formula auditing tools on the Formula Ribbon (That is where they are in excel 2007)?

Comment: Ah, interesting. That looks like the solution. Too bad my computer melts when I try to do it. This article was helpful: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/display-the-relationships-between-formulas-and-cells-HP010066253.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In VBA, Range.Dependents and Range.Precedents will give you this info.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. In Excel, under the Formulas tab, there are two buttons called "Trace Precedents" and "Trace Dependents"

From [Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/display-the-relationships-between-formulas-and-cells-HP010066253.aspx)

> Precedent cells are cells that are referred to by a formula in another
>   cell. For example, if cell D10 contains the formula =B5, cell B5 is a
>   precedent to cell D10.
>
> Dependent cells contain formulas that refer to other cells. For
>   example, if cell D10 contains the formula =B5, cell D10 is a dependent
>   of cell B5.

If the cell is leading to a different worksheet, double click on the arrow leading out of the cell and you can see exactly which cells reference it.

Answer (score 1):

*Fast Manual Solution for `Precedents`*

1. Pick a blank cell in your sheet, type `=` in the formula bar, and then click the area to the left of the `A` and above `1` (in `excel-2007`and higher you will get a formula of `=1:1048576`
2. Excel will complain about a circular reference (if iteration is off).
3. Select this cell, and then `Trace Precedents` twice - this highlights all precedents to the active sheet
4. I have tried the same trick with `Trace Dependents` in xl2010 and xl2013 without success, so you would need to use (3) on the sheets where you think you mights have links back to that data set

Sample file used: http://www.exinfm.com/excel%20files/capbudg.xls

[image]

*Mappit addin*

My free [Mappit addin](http://sdrv.ms/18pQI6C) provides a summary as to how sheets are connected to other sheets in the workbook

[image]